# Как склеить DOC файлы и конвертировать в PDF?

Tags: php, java, node.js, pdf, doc

Как можно склеить несколько .doc файлов в один и конвертировать его в pdf, не теряя картинки и форматирование (хотя бы частично)?

В распоряжении есть php7, java и node.

Comment: Сконвертировать в pdf по отдельности (например LibreOffice), потом склеить pdf-ки в один (например pdftk)

Comment: Конвертирование в pdf занимает очень много времени..

Comment: И что? Вам же всё равно нужен pdf

Comment: То есть Вы не сможете подсказать ничего лучше?)

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает этот вариант?

Answer (score 1):

смотри аналогичный репост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236226/pdf-or-word-creation-documents-with-yii проблема таже.
А вообще если на выходе нужен pdf, так делай сразу pdf, библиотека http://www.fpdf.org/ есть дока на русском.
И присоединяюсь к  Alexey Ten команда объединяет 2 pdf в один `pdftk firstpage.pdf background secondpage.pdf output mergepage.pdf`